# What is the best way to find the closest list to an expected list?

Tags: data-analysis

I am currently working on a program where I try to experimentally come up with an ordering of elements, then compare to a given ordering. For instance:

Experimental: A, C, B, F, E, D
Given: A, B, C, D, E, F

At the end I am trying to find some metric by which I can measure how close my experimental ordering is to the given ordering. I know that all of the same elements will be present in both. Is the number of elements in the correct position divided by the total number of elements in the list the best I can do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this largely depends on how you define similarity between two sequences. I will give you some ideas and then define the corresponding distance function.

1. Just the correct positions matter: In this case you just count the number of correctly positioned elements (as you proposed in your question)
2. The difference to the desired position is important: You could sum up the differences of the position in the experimental to the position in the given sequence for each character
3. The ranking between elements is important: Here you could count how many pairs of elements are in correct order (similar to [Kendall rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient)). Beside this one there are a couple more [rank correlation measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_correlation).
4. The cost to transform one list into the other: In this case you would have to calculate the minimum number of swaps in order to get from one list to the other. If you also care about how far elements are from their desired position you could only allow for swaps of adjacent elements. Computing this, is a little more complicated, but this [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-swaps-required-sort-array/) might help.

If you want to have a distance between 0 and 1 you would have to normalize the results. I am sure there are more, these are just the ones I could think of from the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will go with either the second or fourth option. I definitely want to take distance from desired position into consideration.

Comment: Glad that I could help

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a particular name or process for the third option? I believe it may be the one I'm looking for, but I would need a source to show that it is a legitimate means of comparing two sequences

Comment: I just made this measure up and don't know if there is a name for it. Most similar is [Kendall's rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient). Here are some more [rank correlation statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_correlation)